# Why are the poles of $\frac{f'}{f}$ corresponding to the zeros and poles of $f$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Why are the poles of $\frac{f'}{f}$ corresponding to the zeros and poles of $f$?

Suppose that $a$ is a zero of $f$ of order $m$, then $\frac{f'}{f}$ has a pole at $a$ of residue $m$, suppose that $b$ is a pole of $f$ of order $n$, then $\frac{f'}{f}$ has a zero at $b$ of residue $-n$. Why are these true?

Comment: Write $f(z) = (z-a)^k\cdot g(z)$ in a neighbourhood of $a$ where $g$ is holomorphic, with $g(a) \neq 0$.

Comment: How to get the residue of it?

Comment: If you use that form for $f$, what representation do you get for $\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}$ near $a$?

Comment: I see, but how about poles of $f(z)$ also being the poles of $\frac{f'}{f}$

Comment: If $f$ has a pole at $z_0$, expand $f$ as a Laurent series in a disk centered at $z_0$ with no poles besides $z_0$.

Comment: The same form, just $k < 0$ if $a$ is a pole of $f$.